# Changing container from mkv to m2v - audio doesn't transfer

Tags: ffmpeg

Am converting a DVD extraction from an MKV container to an MPEG2 file.  This is the command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -i title04.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy title04.m2v
```

It creates the file but with no audio.  Am not sure what I am missing as it isn't throwing any error (and usually if a stream isn't compatible with a container it complains).

Here is the output.  Any ideas?

```
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'title04.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libmakemkv v1.8.12 (1.3.0/1.4.1) darwin(x86-release)
    creation_time   : 2014-08-28 19:36:24
  Duration: 00:00:11.34, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4979 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], max. 7500 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Stereo
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle, 720x480 (default)
Output #0, mpeg2video, to 'title04.m2v':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.48.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video, yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, max. 7500 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  340 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4738kB time=00:00:11.31 bitrate=3431.4kbits/s
video:4738kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m2v (mpeg 2 video) is a video only container. The audio stream is not included.
You should use .mpg or .mpeg as container format.

Comment: That got me on the right track - although I still couldn't copy the audio I could downconvert it at least and hear something.  Thanks for that.  Whoops.